# Code to delete rows for a table not working Javascript / HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with the following code. I am trying remove rows from a table if that row does not contain the meat in the td. To clarify, when the function is called, it takes in 2. (Which is where the word meat can be found in the table)
Some of the rows do not contain the word meat, x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[a]; The word meat can be found in [a] of the row. I think the problem is with x.innerHTML, as I don't think it returns a value to compare to b.
Any help or leads are appreciated. Right now when the button is clicked to call the function, nothing happens.

```
function clearTable(a) {
            var table, rows, switching, i, x, c, shouldSwitch;
            table = document.getElementById("Invtable");
            switching = true;
            var b = "meat";

            while (switching){

                switching = false;
                rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

                for (i = 0; i < (rows.length); i++) {
                    shouldSwitch = false;
                    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[a];

                    if(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() !=  b){


                        shouldSwitch= true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (shouldSwitch) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    switching = true;
                }
            }
        }

 var table = "<tr>";
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        if (j == 6) {
            table += "<td> <img src='CSV_Photos/" + array[i][j] + "' style ='width:250px;height:250px'>" + "<br>" //every 6th column is a picture 
            + "<center> " + '<button id="btn" onClick="clickMe(\''+ array[i][1] + ',' + array[i][5] + '\')"> Buy / Add To Cart </button> </td>' + "</center>"; //button onclick takes (name+price)
        } else {
            table += "<td>" + array[i][j] + "</td>";
        }
    }
  table += "</tr>";
}
```

Edit: Starting from the var table, that's how the table was made in javascript in a function.

The table code in html looks like this :

```
<tr><td>1000</td><td>Chicken</td><td>Meat</td><td>Perfect</td><td>Yes</td><td>$2.99</td><td>image</td> </tr>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample table (HTML)?

Comment: can you please post your HTML

Comment: When you step through this in your debugger, where/how specifically does it fail?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: Oh I forgot about the debugger. When it runs, it says that x is undefined.

Comment: More specifically x is undefined in this line  if(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() !=  b){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are passing the incorrect column number as the argument. You only have two `td` per row and the index starts at `0`. So you have to pass `1` as your argument: `clearTable(1)`.

I created a simple table so you can see your function works with the correct argument.

**EDIT**

I recreated my table to have 6 columns and I created a button that runs the function onClick.

```js
   
var table = '<table id="Invtable"><tr><td>Food</td><td>chicken</td><td>Veggies</td><td>Ceral</td><td>Soda</td><td>Water</td></tr><tr><td>Food</td><td>water</td><td>Soda</td><td>Meat</td><td>Water</td><td>Ceral</td></tr><tr><td>Third-Food</td><td>Meat</td><td>Chicken</td><td>Ceral</td><td>Water</td><td>Soda</td></tr></table>';
var btn = '<button onClick="clearTable(1)">Meat</button>';
document.body.innerHTML = table + btn;

//clearTable(1);

function clearTable(a) {
            var table, rows, switching, i, x, c, shouldSwitch;
            table = document.getElementById("Invtable");
            switching = true;
            var b = "meat";

            while (switching){

                switching = false;
                rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        console.log(rows);
                for (i = 0; i < (rows.length); i++) {
                    shouldSwitch = false;
                    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[a];

                    if(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() !=  b){


                        shouldSwitch= true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (shouldSwitch) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    switching = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, and x is still undefined when I run the debugger.

Comment: what is `array` in your  code? when you are creating the table?

Comment: array is a 2D array, within every one row is 6 columns.

Comment: can you post it? also, how are you calling the function? is it inline on an HTML element?

Comment: The function clearTable is being called by an HTML element. This is how <button class="dropbtn" onclick="clearTable(1)"> Meat </button> Furthmore array is a big array that is creating with a csv file. But essentially, [0][0] is 1000, [0][1] is Chicken, [0][2] is Meat, [0][3] is blah all the way to [0][6] which is something else. And this continues essentially but the elements in the array aren't the same of course.

Comment: @DaNubCake I reformatted the table with 6 columns and created a button that runs the function onClick and it works. The problem might be with how the table is actually created but I would have to see the array. Try copying the first 6 rows of the CSV file to see if we can find the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145924/discussion-between-danubcake-and-josan-iracheta).

Comment: How did you end up fixing it?

Comment: Essentially I had to do if (rows) { before the if(x.innerHTML line
and then my meat variable was suppose to be " meat" with a space before it, because that is how the csv file was made
But, you have been very helpful and I appreciate you willing to take the time to help me!

Comment: No problem im glad you were able to figure it out